# EntityFramework Data Initialization

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework Code First.  The database initialization works great for creating the database and tables.

I was wondering if there's a way to make the process less destructive... rather than issuing DROP / CREATE statements when the schema changes, is there any way (via an off-the-shelf Initializer, or otherwise) to issue ALTER statements to update my schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into Code First Data Migrations, I've not used it myself but I believe it's what you are looking for.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx

To help those that come along later, you should be able to follow these instructions to get it all setup : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what I'm looking for - heres a good link that helped me get it set up.  Please add it to your answer for those who come later and I will accept your answer.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx
There is an example of using custom method to initialize data.